# How to store the content in this format in the mysql database?

Tags: mysql, database-design

How to store the content in this format in the mysql database?

```
Text 1
Image 1
Text 2
Image2......
```

So when I retrieve it ..I can display in the same format

Comment: Data storage and data display have almost nothing to do with each other, so the question is rather meaningless.

Answer (score 0):

You can put text and image Path in the table, and use this path to retrieve it.

Answer (score 0):

You will be outputting the text.  You will be wrapping the link to the image in an `<img...>` tag, so both are `TEXT`.  So something like:

```
CREATE TABLE stuff (
     article_id ..., 
     sequence SMALLINT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
     is_image TINYINT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
     text_or_image MEDIUMINT NOT NULL,
     PRIMARY KEY(article_id, sequence)
) ENGINE=InnoDB;
```